# SQL Server return Rows that are not equal <> to a value and NULL

Tags: sql-server, null

I have a table that has a column of values that can be rowTypeID = (1,2,3, or null) .  I would like to write a query that returns any row that doesn't have a value of 3 in it.  In this example I want all NULL rows along with all 1,2 rows I just don't want rows with the value of 3

Set ANSI null ON  is currently set for the database.

I'm curious as to why I can't write

```
select * from myTable where myCol <> 3
```

This query will not return any rows that have NULL in the myCol  column

I have to write

```
select * from my Table where myCol <> 3 or myCol Is NULL
```

Do I always have to include the IS NULL or can I set it up so a where clause myCol  <>3 will return rows that have Null as value for my Col

Comment: That's the way NULL works, any comparison with it is false except for IS NULL and IS NOT NULL

Comment: @kurosch: Stricly following your line, NULL = NULL would also return false, since it is a comparison?

Comment: @Marcel: yes, NULL = NULL is always false, and for that matter so is NULL <> NULL :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think your approach is fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE myCol <> 3 OR myCol IS NULL
```

Since you are asking for alternatives, another way to do it is to make your column `NOT NULL` and store another (otherwised unused) value in the database instead of `NULL` - for example `-1`. Then the expression `myCol <> 3` will match your fake-`NULL` just as it would with any other value.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE myCol <> 3
```

However in general I would recommend **not** to use this approach. The way you are already doing it is the right way.

Also it might be worth mentioning that several other databases support `IS DISTINCT FROM` which does exactly what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE myCol IS DISTINCT FROM 3
```

MySQL has the [NULL-safe equal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) which can also be used for this purpose:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT myCol <=> 3
```

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't yet support either of these syntaxes.

Comment: Please upvote this ISO feature on MS site, "DISTINCT PREDICATE" : https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate

Answer (score 3):

You must handle the NULLs one way or another, since expressions involving `NULL` [evaluate to Unknown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29). If you want, you could instead do:

```
select *
from MyTable
where isnull(MyColumn, -1) <> 3
```

But this involves a magic number (-1), and is arguably less readable than the original test for `IS NULL`.

**Edit:** and, as SQLMenace points out, is not [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: select *
from MyTable
where isnull(MyColumn, 3) = 3

Comment: @SQLMenace: good point, will also perform worse - I do not recommend my suggestion.

Comment: @Yossarian - this is better than my magic number version, but I still find the readbility worse. I woudl stick with standard test for `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you test for a value all NULLs are omitted – after all, you are testing whether the value in some column passes certain criteria and NULL is *not a value*.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I always have to include the IS NULL or can I set it up so a where clause myCol <>3 will return rows that have Null as value for my Col?

You *always*, **always**, always have to include `is null`.

Because 3 does not equal Not/Applicable  and it does not equal Unkown.

Answer (score 0):

because you can't compare NULL to anything else, NULL is not even  equal to NULL

```
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @i2 INT

SELECT @i = NULL, @i2 = NULL

IF @i = @i2
PRINT 'equal'
ELSE 
PRINT 'not equal'
```